# Align middle a div in another div (glitch)

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

[You can find jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pho3nixHun/H8Tsc/1/)

As you probably see on the picture I trying to align middle a circle (div, green) into another circle (div, grey). I calculated the center of both div and made them equal, but the little green circle is still not in the middle.

Where is the mistake? I just can't find it.

The jquery I use to align circle (where `o` is the green circle, and `$(this)` is the grey one:

```
$.fn.center = function(o) {
  var _X = parseInt(o.css('left')) + parseInt(o.width())/2 - parseInt($(this).width())/2;
  var _Y = parseInt(o.css('top')) + parseInt(o.height())/2 - parseInt($(this).height())/2;
  $(this).offset({ top: _Y, left: _X });
};
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I suggest using jQuery UI's [position](http://jqueryui.com/position/) method. It allows you to position any element relative to any other element and abstracts all of the complications.

Comment: +1 to add the solution to the end of the question

Comment: You're welcome. And for anyone else interested. This would be the working example using `.position()`: 
    $(this).position({
        my: 'center center',
        at: 'center center',
        of: o
    });

Comment: If you post the code, I'll mark as proper solution! :)

Comment: bizzare... I put 50% top and left, on all 3 fields... wow, interesting question.

Comment: Please post the solution as an *answer*, and then accept that answer when you're able.

Comment: In the absence of @ogc-nick's answer post, I posted the recommended solution as a community wiki. If Nick wishes to post and take credit, the wiki answer can be removed.

Comment: jsFiddle project updated!

Comment: The reason the code above does not work as it should is due to parseInt(). It rounds to a whole integer number which results in your calulations shifting up or down and therefor changing the location of the circle. You can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Theoretically if I replace `parseInt` to `parseFloat` will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery UI's `position` method. It allows you to position any element relative to any other element and abstracts all of the complications. (Courtesy of [ogc-nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863924/ogc-nick)).

```
$.fn.center = function(o) {
    $(this).position({
      my: "center middle",
      at: "center middle",
      of: o
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work better for you:
HTML:

```
   <div id="range_sword"> 
    <div class="jk"></div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.range_sword, body, div{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.jk{
    display: block;
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}

#range_sword{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width:2px;
    padding:15px;
}
#range_sword:hover{
    background-color:#cdcdcd;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#range_sword").draggable();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H8Tsc/2/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method by far would've been to drop the JS and just use CSS pseudo elements (not supported in IE7 and below).

http://jsfiddle.net/rzGX9/

```
.small-circle { position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 20px; background: #f00; }
.small-circle:after { z-index: -1; content:""; position: absolute;  background: #00f; border-radius: 50px; width: 50px; height: 50px; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; display: none;}
.small-circle:hover:after { display: block; }
```